# Rails 3.1.3 on Heroku: (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've installed a few basic apps on Heroku without problem, and this one (Rails 3.1.3) seemed fine in that it showed Rails welcome page

```
public/index.html.erb
```

but when I removed that page and then set

```
root :to => 'users#index'
```

I got a problem. In the heroku logs it said there's a routing error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
```

Does anyone know what this is about?

```
2012-01-14T21:48:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-01-14T21:48:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2012-01-14T21:48:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-01-14T21:48:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:32570, CTRL+C to stop
2012-01-14T21:48:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-01-14T21:48:35+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 216.251.147.10 at 2012-01-14 13:48:36 -0800
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:35+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=5907
2012-01-14T21:48:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=30ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 216.251.147.10 at 2012-01-14 13:48:46 -0800
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionC

2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=5907
2012-01-14T21:48:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=5907
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 216.251.147.10 at 2012-01-14 13:48:59 -0800
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
2012-01-14T21:48:59+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 216.251.147.10 at 2012-01-14 13:49:18 -0800
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
2012-01-14T21:49:18+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 216.251.147.10 at 2012-01-14 13:49:33 -0800
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:49:34+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=5907
2012-01-14T21:49:33+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:49:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=5907
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 216.251.147.10 at 2012-01-14 13:50:21 -0800
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:50:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-14T21:52:42+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-01-14T21:52:54+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 983a24d by m73mitchell@gmail.com
2012-01-14T21:52:54+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by m73mitchell@gmail.com
2012-01-14T21:52:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2012-01-14T21:52:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2012-01-14T21:52:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-01-14T21:52:55+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-01-14T21:53:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-01-14T21:53:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=37ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:53:17+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:53:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:53:38+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=107ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:53:40+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:53:49+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-01-14T21:53:52+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-01-14T21:53:57+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-01-14T21:53:57+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited
2012-01-14T21:55:15+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=35ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:55:17+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:55:22+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-01-14T21:56:18+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mmcarrier.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=728
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you may not have precompiled your assets before you pushed to Heroku, try:

```
rake assets:precompile
git add .
etc etc
```

I think that should help. For more information, see here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Comment: you're right, i didn't and I'll do it, but why did the  Rails welcome page work?

Comment: It worked because there are no assets necessary for the welcome page. All the styles are included in the public/index.html file and it doesn't require any javascripts or images. Glad I could help!

Comment: Simple, it is not a asset, it's view.

Answer (score 11):

**No need to precompile** and *clutter* your git!

heroku will precompile your assets

with rails **3.1.x** you added this to *application.rb*

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

UPDATE 16th july2012

also rails **3.2.x**

it seems to be problem with ActiveRecord and database.yml ! If you don't use regular database, but use MongoDB, you will not need the above. However, if you do, you'll need to disable the initilize, as activerecord reads database tables when initializing, but database is not available at precompile phase at heroku.

with **MongoDB it is not necessary**.

/UPDATE

**rails 3.2.x**
: Have a look at the top of **application.rb**. The  OMA comments are mine, added for clarity

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  "OMA - comment this line"
  #Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  "OMA - uncomment this line"
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Comment: I'm running Rails 3.2.6 with everything updated and I had to precompile, otherwise rails.png not shown. I am following the Rails Tutorial online book.

Comment: Dang... wish I had read this before I tried Jesse's answer. Simply precompiling did not help. And yeah... now my git repo is bloated.

Answer (score 2):

To get lazy initiation working with thin (on heroku) with rails 3.2.3 I had to do:

In config/application.rb:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

...


module Romulo
  class Application < Rails::Application

...

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # get precompilation working on heroku:
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true

    config.serve_static_assets = false
  end
end
```

In config/environments/production.rb:

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

No need to precompile assets.